# Organizing a Cloud Firestore database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, database-design

I can't manage to determine what is the better way of organizing my database for my app :

My users can create items identified by a unique ID.

**The queries I need :**

- **Query 1:** Get all the items created by a user

- **Query 2** : From the UID of an item, get its creator

My database is organized as following :

**Users database**

```
user1 : {
     item1_uid,
     item2_uid
},
user2 : {
     item3_uid
}
```

**Items database**

```
item1_uid : {
     title,
     description
},
item2_uid : {
     title,
     description
},
item3_uid : {
     title,
     description
}
```

For the **query 2,** its quite simple but for the **query 2**, I need to parse all the users database and list all the items Id to see if there is the one I am looking for. It works right now but I'm afraid that it will slow the request time as the database grows.

Should I add in the items data a row with the user id ? If yes the query will be simpler but I heard that I am not supposed to have twice the same data in the database because it can lead to conflicts when adding or removing items.

Answer (score 3):

> Should I add in the items data a row with the user id ?

Yes, this is a very common approach in the NoSQL world and is called **denormalization**. Denormalization is described, in this ["famous" post](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) about NoSQL data modeling, as "*copying of the same data into multiple documents in order to simplify/optimize query processing or to fit the user’s data into a particular data model*". In other words, the main driver of your data model design is the queries you plan to execute.

More concretely you could have an extra field in your `item` documents, which contain the ID of the creator. You could even have another one with, e.g., the name of the creator: This way, in one query, you can display the items and their creators.

---

Now, for maintaining these different documents in sync (for example, if you change the name of one user, you want it to be updated in the corresponding items), you can either use a [Batched Write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) to modify several documents in one atomic operation, or rely on one or more [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) that would detect the changes of the `user` documents and reflect them in the `item` documents.